# JTextField setEnabled vs setEditable

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

What is the difference between `JTextField.setEnabled()` and `JTextField.setEditable()`?
In my code I have an Instance of a class inherited from `JTextField`. But when I set its property `setEnabled(false)` I can still edit and process its contents in my program. However when I set its property `setEditable(false)` I can no longer edit its text. If it is so. Then what is the purpose of `setEnabled()` property here?

My Code for inherited class is:

```
 private static class CCField extends JTextField{
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      public CCField() {
        this( DEFAULT_COLUMN_COUNT );
      }

      public CCField(final int cols) {
        super( cols );
 }
```

**Added INFO**
When I call the `setEnabled()` property of this class it does not show any effect on the text field and it still remains enabled. I have a container `Jcomponent` in my code which have this `CCField` as a child component. So when I try to disable it using `setEnabled(false)` it still editable. Whereas when I try to disable it using `setEditable(false)` then it is disabled.
This is how I am accessing this textField in my container:

```
 JComponent jComp = DDEUtil.getComponent(icTableLayout,icDS);
 ((JTextField)jComp.getComponent(1)).setEditable(false);
```

And what is going on in `DDEUtil.getComponent` is too complex as it involve a number of classes and not possible to post here.

I wonder I have not overridden any method of this component so why is it showing this behavior.

Comment: Post a complete program demonstrating the problem. `setEnabled(false)` disables a text field completely. `setEditable(false)` still allows selecting and copying its content, but doesn't allow modifying its value.

Comment: @JBNizet I think that qualifies to be an answer...

Comment: @JimGarrison: I think that the actual question is: why setEnabled(false) doesn't disable my text field. But the OP needs to post more code to have an answer to this question.

Comment: _When I call the setEnabled() property of this class it does not show any effect on the text field and it still remains enabled._ Something wrong in the code you are not showing ;-) So either post a SSCCE or solve it without help, nobody can guess which invisible line is wrong ...

Comment: I have show every thing except `DDEUtil.getComponent` which is too large, complex and generic, as it is generating a lot of components using reflection.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In my case `setEditable(false)` is graying the field and `setEnabled(false)` not graying the field.

> **TextField are editable by default. The code setEditable(false) makes the TextField uneditable. It is still selectable and the user can copy data from it, but the user cannot change the TextField's contents directly.**

---

> **The code setEnabled(false), disables this TextField. It is not selectable and the user can not copy data from it and the user cannot change the TextField's contents directly.**

---

**Useful Links**

1. [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)
2. [Component#setEnabled()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html)

Comment: Very strange this is, IMHO the "official" is that disabled are totally grayed out. Editable simply lock the field but "only" change its background grayed while the text keeps readable. Can you confirm and probably improve your answer? Tested with Java 1.8.

Comment: In my case, there's definitely no greying with `setEditable(false)`

Answer (score 3):

While `setEnabled(false)` grays out the field comletely, `setEditable(false)` just prevents it from beeing edited, but it will still look the same.

Comment: not in my case. Here `setEditable(false)` is graying the field whereas `setEnabled(false)` is doing nothing...

Comment: It works perfect, there must be something wrong in the code of `CCField`

Comment: Though it does not solve the problem but still I got the answer of my actual question i.e. Different b/w `setEnabled` and `setEditable`

Comment: Could you post the entire code of CCField? It would help a lot

Comment: Whole class of CCField is already posted in original question.

Comment: Worked like a charm :)